# OpenCV Python copying certain portion of image to another

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to calculate the difference betwwn two images. I'm only interested in the difference value for a certain portion of image. For that i am copying the required portion of image to a temp images, and operating on those images. However using the pixel allocation using as specified on http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html. Here it is given,

`ball = img[280:340, 330:390]
 img[273:333, 100:160] = ball`

Using the similar logic, i have written a python program,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_file = 'carparking2_1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_withoutcar = 'carparking2_1.jpg'
img_withcar = 'carparking2.jpg'

img1 = img_withoutcar[47:151, 106:157]
img2 = img_withcar[47:151, 106:157]

diff1 = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
diff2 = cv2.absdiff(img1, img1)

print 'RGB shape: ', img.shape        # Rows, cols, channels
print 'Difference with car and without: ', diff1
print 'Difference with car and with car: ', diff2
```

However, im getting the output message:

```
File "D:/Projects/IoT Smart Parking/differenceinframes.py", line 8, in <module>
    img1 = img_withoutcar[47:151, 106:157]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I am running Python 2.7 with OpenCV 3.1.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because your command is trying to slice the string 'carparking2_1.jpg' as if it were the image data.

```
#First assign the file names:
file_name_without_car='carparking2_1.jpg'
file_name_with_car='carparking2.jpg'

#load the images
img_withoutcar= cv2.imread(file_name_without_car, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_withcar= cv2.imread(file_name_with_car, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

#now you can slice regions of the images
#note that color images have a third dimension for color channel.
img1 = img_withoutcar[47:151, 106:157,:]
img2 = img_withcar[47:151, 106:157,:]
```